# What does this tablature notation mean?

Tags: guitar, notation, tablature

[image: tablature]

There are two lines which have the number 0.
Does that mean that I need to play two strings at once?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It means that you have to play the two open strings at once, followed by a hammer-on on the B-string only, while keeping the E-string playing.

More in general, any numbers on tablature that are immediately under one another should be played at the same time as a chord. The zero just says they should be played at the zero'th fret - ie the nut, which means play an open string.